# Closures and jQuery draggable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

After reading for some hours about closures, I think that they're what I'm trying to archieve here. However, the code is not working. What am I missing here?

```
(function( id ){
    return function(){
        jQuery("#rep-element-" + ( id ) ).draggable({ drag: function(){ processMove( ( id ) ); } } ); 
    }
} )(window.conceptMapReplica.length + 1);
```

This piece of code is inside a loop. The idea is that it gets the "id" variable from the global var "window.conceptMapReplica" and then creates a jQuery.draggable() based on the "id". However, the code apparently just does nothing at all.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

All your top level function does is return an anonymous function. You need to also invoke **it**.

IOW, try add one more `()`

Comment: Well, that actually solved something. But the jQuery draggable still does nothing. Any more suggestions?

Comment: The code you posted is very incomplete so it's hard to help you debug it. It could also benefit from further formatting/indentation.

Comment: Well, the code it quite big and it's impractical to put it here... But considering that the only problem is in the jQuery line, is it correct or did I miss something?